# How to filter something using predicates in Neo4j?

Tags: filter, neo4j, cypher

I have first query like:

```
MATCH (U:User)-[S:Has|Shout]->(P:Post)
WHERE U.user_id=1
RETURN U.username, P.post
```

Query above will return all result from user_id=1 like:

```
U.username  P.post
rioeduardo  tomorrow
rioeduardo  hurray
rioeduardo  lala
rioeduardo  hey
rioeduardo  nice
rioeduardo  testing
```

And I have second query like:

```
MATCH (U:User)-[S:Shout]->(P:Post)<-[:Has]-(FU:User)
WHERE U.user_id=1
RETURN U.username, P.post
```

Query above will return all result from user_id=1 and others user also have it:

```
U.username  P.post
rioeduardo  tomorrow
rioeduardo  hurray
rioeduardo  lala
rioeduardo  hey
```

nah, I want to remove the result from user_id=1 and others user also have it, so the result will be:

```
U.username  P.post
rioeduardo  nice
rioeduardo  testing
```

I already tried using predicates in Neo4j but I got nothing. The query is like:

```
MATCH (U:User)-[S:Has|Shout]->(P:Post), filter=(U:User)-[:Shout]->(P:Post)<-[:Has]-(FU:User)
WHERE U.user_id=1 AND NONE (x IN nodes(filter) WHERE x.user_id = 1)
RETURN U.username, P.post
```

So, please help me how to solve this, if you have another way, just let me know(It doesn't have to be predicates.)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```
MATCH (U:User)-[S:Has|Shout]->(P:Post)
WHERE U.user_id=1 AND NOT (U:User)-[:Shout]->(P:Post)<-[:Has]-(:User)
RETURN U.username, P.post
```

Comment: It said `FU not defined (line 2, column 64)
"WHERE U.user_id=1 AND NOT (U:User)-[:Shout]->(P:Post)<-[:Has]-(FU:User)"`. It works only if I remove FU `MATCH (U:User)-[S:Has|Shout]->(P:Post)
WHERE U.user_id=1 AND NOT (U:User)-[:Shout]->(P)<-[:Has]-()
RETURN U.username, P.post` nah What should I do to keep the FU?